# Add additional page number, from original work, in margin

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, line-numbering

In [this beautiful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1324/22939) example from [frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/411/frabjous) the original page numbers from the source is place in the margin (below is a screenshot of page 8, which is page 9 and 10, marked by a red marker in the text, in the original)

[image: some of page 9 and 10 of Bertrand Russell Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy]

frabjous has made [a very beautiful website where the code is available](http://people.umass.edu/klement/russell-imp.html), but the specif code to make the  original page numbers in the margin is quite elaborate.

Does anyone here know if there is a package to do this or maybe an easier solution the the one used by frabjous?

Comment: Why not just use a `\marginpar`?

Comment: @Werner, Thanks for responding to my question. I think I got deterred as frabjous wrote that he _had better luck with `marginnote` than with LaTeX's `\marginpar` command_. I'll experiment with `\marginpar`. Thanks.

Comment: @Werner, I added it there to allow you to answer, as it was more or less the answer you suggested in your comment. I'll move it into an separate answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After being encouraged by [Werner's comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174722/add-additional-page-number-from-original-work-in-margin#comment404214_174722) I experimented with `\marginpar{}`, and after that `\marginnote{}`. Apparently it wasn't as complicated as I had imagined. I got this nice result with `\marginnote{}` (see below for code)

[image: marginnote solved the problem]

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
   \verb!\marginpar{}! used {\color{red}$|$} \marginpar{ {\color{red}$7$}} 
    \lipsum[1] 
   \verb!\marginnote{}!  used {\color{red}$|$}  \marginnote{{\color{red}$ 8$}}
        \lipsum[1] 
\end{document}
```