# 'stack' several page numbers on one PDF page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I like to take bits of, often older texts, and place it in a nice looking PDF/LaTeX file. Often several pages of the older text fits on to one PDF letter page. I would like to find a way to make the text *flow freely* on the PDF pages, but the page numbering on the PDF to match the original text. I have previously used [a method with an additional page number, from the original work, in the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174740/22939), but I wonder if there is a way to play more loosely with the LaTeX page numbering?

I've tried to illustrate what I am looking for below.

```
+------------------------+    +------------------------+    +------------------------+
|  A ........... 1       |    |                        |    |                        |
|  B ........... 4       |    | \section{C}            |    |                        |
|  C ........... 5       |    | \setcounter{page}{6}   |    |                        |
|  D ........... 6       |    |                        |    | \section{F}            |
|  E ........... 7       |    |                        |    |  Lorem ipsum dolor     |
|  F ........... 8       |    | \section{D}            |    |  dolor sit amet.       |
|                        |    |                        |    |  Duis in sodales,      |
| \section{A}            |    | \setcounter{page}{7}   |    |  vulputate ligula.     |
| \setcounter{page}{4}   |    | \section{E}            |    |                        |
| \section{B}            |    |                        |    |                        |
|          1/4           |    |         5/6/7          |    |           8            |
+------------------------+    +------------------------+    +------------------------+
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit what do you mean by `play more loosely'?

Comment: @MMA, Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. I would like to have several page numbers on each PDF and be able to, somehow, control where a new page begins, like in my mini illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how robust this is, but here's an implementation that might work for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr, afterpage}
\newcommand{\newpagenumber}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\newpagenumber}

\makeatletter
\let\old@addcontentsline\addcontentsline% Store original \addcontentsline
\newcommand{\setnextsectionpage}[1]{% \setnextsectionpage{<new page number>}
  \afterpage{% Adjust things after this page
    \setcounter{page}{\numexpr#1+1}% Correct page number
    \gdef\newpagenumber{\thepage}}% Restore single page number as footer
  \g@addto@macro{\newpagenumber}{/#1}% Append new (false) page number
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{%
    % Falsify \thepage to be a page that is specifically set
    \addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{#1}}%
    \let\addcontentsline\old@addcontentsline}% Restore default behaviour
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents% Page 1

\section{First section}% Page 1
\setnextsectionpage{4}
\section{Second section}% Page 4

\clearpage
\section{Third section}% Page 5

\setnextsectionpage{6}
\section{Fourth section}% Page 6

\setnextsectionpage{7}
\section{Fifth section}% Page 7

\clearpage
\section{Last section}% Page 8

\end{document}
```

While constructing the page, the page footer is amended with whatever "false pages" you have on the current page. Then [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) is used to correct the page number and restore the default `\thepage` footer.

A slight modification to `\addcontentsline` allows us to insert whatever page number we decide, as designated by `\setnextsectionpage{<new page number>}`.